# Input double into int variable using istream encounting error

Tags: c++, iostream

Under windows10 and VS2017:

I was trying to read a double number `1.1` from keyboard using istream and put it into a int type variable, say `temp`. In reason `temp` is `1` but the istream seems to be stuck in some error status. In expectancy istream should stop and wait for keyboard input but it continues another round read-from-buffer and error occurs this time.

I had checked the `rdstate()` and it was equal to `2` after the 2nd round read-from-buffer. I know it was abnormal but why?

To replicate, run the code, type `1.1` in console and hit enter, the error will show up.

---

Actually, I used int32 to try to store double for some reasons. The program is supposed to print valid input from keyboard. Here valid refers to that the input should not exceed the range of int32 or be double/readable character. Otherwise the program should print `Invalid input` on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>

std::istream& f(std::istream &in) {
    int temp = 0;
    while(true) { 
        while (in >> temp) {
            if (temp == -1) {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        }
        if (in.eof()|| temp == -1) break;
        if (!in) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input"  << std::endl;
            in.clear();
            in.ignore(10000,32);
        }
    }
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    return in;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Please input some integers and end with ^Z or -1" << std::endl;
    f(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you read `1.1` from the keyboard you're reading **text**. The program looks at that text and decides what value it represents, depending on the type of the variable that you're reading into. If you're reading into an `int`, the input routine reads the first '1', then sees '.', which can't be part of the text representation of an `int`, and it stops reading. Your variable gets the value 1. If you try to read another `int` from the same input stream, that '.' will stop the read immediately, since it can't be part of an `int`, and the attempted input fails.

Short answer: don't do that. If your input **text** looks like floating-point, read it as floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

std::istream& f(std::istream &in) {
    std::string temp = "";
    while(true) { 
        while (in >> temp) {
            if (temp == "-1") {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        }
        if (in.eof()|| temp == "-1") break;
        if (!in) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input"  << std::endl;
            in.clear();
            in.ignore(10000,32);
        }
    }
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    return in;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Please input some integers and end with ^Z or -1" << std::endl;
    f(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

You are parsing character by character from the buffer. You cannot put a character into an integer. You are assuming you are reading `1.1` from the stream, but you're instead reading `1`,`.`,`1` from the buffer, and the `.` is throwing the error. The above portion works as you are reading characters and keeping them in a string.

Comment: Check out my input and output, as using string for BigInt data, it compiles output successfully: https://ideone.com/gSOtcV

Comment: I had the same idea. But when I tried to input a big integer which is out of the int32 range, the istream would not input any value to `temp`. Instead, it directly jump out of the inner loop and print `Invalid input` on the screen. If the istream read bit by bit, it should put part of the integer into `temp`, isn't it? Btw, I have explained why I use int32 to store input in the problem statement.

Comment: If you provide a bigInt input, and keep in a int, it will overflow. If you want to check for valid int32 and decimal, you can add each character read to a result string, and then use `stoi()` method to parse the string as int and compare with your values to detect it is valid or not.